# How to read useful content from another website using c#

Tags: c#

I need to create a tool for market purpose. What i want is an interface in which i out any url so it goes to that url and fetch information like the price of the product and features other's are providing. Based on this our owners can take decision to set feasible price of same product we have. So i need to have any DLL or JS or anything which helps me to read information from other website using c#.
Any Help?

Comment: Are you looking for someone to write the software for you?

Comment: As written, this is nearly hopelessly broad.  Screen-scraping is a very general topic.

Comment: Nice question.... Very LOL

Comment: Take a look at [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: would you prefer the db scripts aswell? or just the C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `WebClient`:

```
using (var client = new WebClient()) {
    string value = client.DownloadString("http://www.example.com/productXDetails.html");
    int price = parseSiteHTML(value); 
}
```

Parsing the HTML is the tricky part; you need to know where in the site's HTML the pricing information is.  The HTML agility pack (thanks @tnw for mentioning it) will help with that step.

Comment: If the question were "How do I download the entire HTML of a webpage as a string", this would be an answer. Unfortunately the question isn't even remotely answered by this at the moment. I think we both know that this question is way to broad to be feasibly answered. -1, consider adding this as a comment instead.

Comment: @tnw Agreed that this question is too broad.  I posted this as an answer rather than a comment because the comment box admonished me to avoid answering questions in comments